# Linux Backup MySQL failed when assign to crontab

Tags: mysql, linux, cron

Hi fellow StackOverFlow,

Today , I have a very weird scenario in my Unix machine.

I'm currently using this command manually to save my current database backup.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u root -p'thetechnofreak' admin_test > /mnt/databasesql/admin$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.gz
```

In my crontab , I access it using

```
crontab -e
```

Then I add the following to the list

```
30 2 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root -p'thetechnofreak' admin_test > /mnt/databasesql/admin$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.gz
```

I realize that it's not doing it automatically, is there anything that i've missed?

Is there a flagging option or a logging method to know whether the backup is done successfully or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with the escaping of a `\` prior to the `%`

```
30 2 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root -p'thetechnofreak' admin_test > /mnt/databasesql/admin$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H.\%M.\%S).sql.gz
```

See [Using the % Character in Crontab Entries](http://www.ducea.com/2008/11/12/using-the-character-in-crontab-entries/) by M. Ducea